# ExoPlayer TrackSelectionDialog comparator not working

Tags: java, android, comparator, exoplayer

I am printing video tracks to user in "height" + "p" format.
By default `TrackSelectionDialog` printing them let's say in random order. I want to reorder them from min to max.

So I have this in my `TrackSelectionView` `init`:

```
/**
 * Initialize the view to select tracks for a specified renderer using {@link MappedTrackInfo} and
 * a set of {@link DefaultTrackSelector.Parameters}.
 *
 * @param mappedTrackInfo The {@link MappedTrackInfo}.
 * @param rendererIndex The index of the renderer.
 * @param isDisabled Whether the renderer should be initially shown as disabled.
 * @param overrides List of initial overrides to be shown for this renderer. There must be at most
 *     one override for each track group. If {@link #setAllowMultipleOverrides(boolean)} hasn't
 *     been set to {@code true}, only the first override is used.
 * @param trackFormatComparator An optional comparator used to determine the display order of the
 *     tracks within each track group.
 * @param listener An optional listener for track selection updates.
 */
public void init(
        MappedTrackInfo mappedTrackInfo,
        int rendererIndex,
        boolean isDisabled,
        List<SelectionOverride> overrides,
        @Nullable Comparator<Format> trackFormatComparator,
        @Nullable TrackSelectionListener listener) {
    this.mappedTrackInfo = mappedTrackInfo;
    this.rendererIndex = rendererIndex;
    this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
    if (trackFormatComparator == null)
        this.trackInfoComparator = null;
    else
        this.trackInfoComparator = new Comparator<TrackInfo>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(TrackInfo o1, TrackInfo o2) {
                return trackFormatComparator.compare(o1.format, o2.format);
            }
        };
    this.listener = listener;
    int maxOverrides = allowMultipleOverrides ? overrides.size() : Math.min(overrides.size(), 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < maxOverrides; i++) {
        SelectionOverride override = overrides.get(i);
        this.overrides.put(override.groupIndex, override);
    }
    updateViews();
}
```

I've add this to my `TrackSelectionDialog`:

```
public void setTrackFormatComparator(@Nullable Comparator<Format> trackFormatComparator) {
        TrackSelectionDialog.trackFormatComparator = trackFormatComparator;
    }
```

and uncomment `trackFormatComparator` in `onCreateView` of `TrackSelectionViewFragment` (in `TrackSelectionDialog` class):

```
    trackSelectionView.init(
            mappedTrackInfo,
            rendererIndex,
            isDisabled,
            overrides,
            trackFormatComparator  /*null*/,
            /* listener= */ this);
```

Then in my player activity I wrote this to sort video tracks by frame height:

```
        TrackSelectionDialog trackSelectionDialog = TrackSelectionDialog.createForTrackSelector(
                trackSelector, dismissedDialog -> isShowingTrackSelectionDialog = false);
        trackSelectionDialog.setTrackFormatComparator((o1, o2) -> Math.max(o1.height, o2.height));
        trackSelectionDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
```

But nothing happens. **Video tracks still sorted default.**

What is wrong with my code or what part of code I've forgot?